# Is there a way to declare a type for a value that possibly extends some other type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In Typescript, can we create a type `Possibly<T>` that only accepts values that maybe, but not necessarily, extend `T`? Or in other words, values that could be asserted `as T` without a "neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other" error?

Alternative ways of constraining the parameter that are not describable as a utility type are also fine. However, they must work at compile time (this is a Typescript question after all, not Javascript).

```
// NOTE: AliveCat and DeadCat are examples, not actual types that can be modified.
//       Assume that asserting (casting) a DeadCat to AliveCat is a compile error.
declare const garfield: AliveCat;
declare const tom: DeadCat;
declare const schrodingersCat: AliveCat | DeadCat;

function feed(cat: Possibly<AliveCat>) {
    if (unspecifiedAliveCheck(cat)) {
        unspecifiedCastOrUnwrap(cat).food++;
    } else {
        throw new Error(" :( ");
    }
}

garfield as Alive; // obviously works, probably warns about being useless
feed(garfield); // so should also work

schrodingersCat as AliveCat; // compiles
feed(schrodingersCat); // so should also compile

tom as AliveCat; // doesn't compile: "neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other"
feed(tom); // so should not compile either
```

Not solutions, because they accept a `DeadCat`:

```
declare function feed(cat: AliveCat | DeadCat);
declare function feed(cat: unknown);
declare function feed(cat: any); // yuk!
```

Or for a more mundane example:

```
// NOTE: the type guard return type is nice to have but optional
function isArray(a: Possibly<any[]>): a is any[] { ... }
isArray([]); // well yeah, but okay, double-checking is fine
isArray(true); // of course not!
isArray(... as true | number); // let's see and find out!
```

Comment: FWIW, I think your example of [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) is a good one for examining type discrimination, and would be useful in the docs (but perhaps others are likely to find it too sensitive a subject).

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] with definitions for `AliveCat` and `DeadCat`?  I'm not sure where you expect `isAlive` to come from.  Is it part of `AliveCat` *and* `DeadCat`?  Is `food` part of `AliveCat`?  Can you explain why you just don't use `type Possibly<T> = any`?  In TypeScript a type that "might extend `T` but maybe not" is essentially `unknown`, but then you're checking `isAlive` without a type assertion, so `any` is the only type that will work here.

Comment: Hmm, is there anything at all that should not be accepted as a `Possibly<AliveCat>`?  I mean, `AliveCat | {isAlive: true, food: string}` would be dangerous if you assume `isAlive === true` implies `typeof food === "number"` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBj8dN).  This really looks like `feed()` should take `AliveCat | DeadCat` or `AliveCat | {food?: never, isAlive?: false | 0 | ""}` or something, but there's no way to get the latter from just `AliveCat`.  If TS had negated types you could write `type Possibly<T>` = T | {[K in keyof T]?: not T[K]}` but it doesn't so we can't.

Comment: All in all it looks like either you want `feed(cat: AliveCat | DeadCat)` or you want `feed(cat: any)`.  If you can describe some other alternative which makes sense, I can investigate producing it programmatically from `AliveCat`.  Let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz this question is purely about the type system and the implementation of feed is not important. `unknown` is not a solution for "possiby alive" because anything can be assigned to it, including "certainly dead". As for an alternative that makes sense, see the isArray example.

Comment: @jcalz Okay I checked and it seems my premise was wrong. It seems like the cast check uses structural typing even for classes, so `tom as AliveCat` is accepted even if `AliveCat` and `DeadCat` are completely unrelated _classes_, as in the updated example. Getting the error to appear requires modifying `DeadCat` to have some incompatible property (but we're not allowed to).

Comment: You need `DeadCat` to have some kind of property to distinguish it from the empty type `{}`.  I don't know what "we're not allowed to" means, but if there's no way for the compiler to see that `DeadCat` is incompatible with `AliveCat` then I'm not sure what you're asking for.  Assuming you actually can distinguish, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAj81W) meet your needs?  There is no type which works how you want but a generic constraint might give a similar result.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz by "we're not allowed to" I mean that I have no control of these hypothetical types. They may come from a library or may be built-in. Just assume that casting a DeadCat to AliveCat is an error, even if the way I declared them it's actually not (which may have caused some confusion, so sorry). Let's replace them with `number` and `boolean` (or indeed with your extended `DeadCat`). The meat of the question is whether we can come up with a `Possibly<boolean>` type that accepts `boolean` and `boolean | number` but not `number`.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom “a type that accepts `boolean` and `boolean | number` but not `number`”: If a type includes a union, then it must also include each of the members of the union: that’s what a union represents. `Exclude<boolean | number, number>` is just `boolean`.

Comment: So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAj81W) work for you or could be made to work?  Where instead of a type (which cannot, by definition, accept `A | B` but reject `A` or `B`.) we use a constraint?

Comment: @jcalz well looks like it does! A constraint is acceptable, though unfortunately rather verbose if it can't be encapsulated in a re-usable utility type.

Comment: @jsejcksn I was afraid so, so I've augmented the question with "alternative ways of constraining the parameter that are not describable as a utility type are also fine".

Comment: So, uh, should I back out of this one?  Looks like various people covered the various angles here; if you are interested in an answer from me, let me know.  Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz actually if you post yours as an answer, it's the one I would accept. Bonus points if you can cook up a version of `feed` that "returns" `asserts cat is AliveCat`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKVPgm) do that for you?  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz once again, the facts speak for themselves, the squiggly lines are in all the right places. And it looks practically usable too. Interesting use of the tuple types in `Possibly`, I'll have to dive into how that works exactly.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom Your question doesn't clarify this: are the real types in question definitely classes?

Comment: @jsejcksn In my question they could be classes, they could be something else, so no, they are not _definitely_ classes. Not that it seems to matter since apparently Typescript does not use nominal typing even for classes (TIL). That said, any solution that somehow only works for classes would still be a welcome contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific type that "maybe, but not necessarily `extends T`" would, almost by necessity, become `unknown`.  If a value of type `AliveCat | SomethingElse` should be a valid `Possibly<AliveCat>` no matter what `SomethingElse` is, you pretty quickly widen `Possibly` to `unknown` or `any`.  And if you want `AliveCat | SomethingElse` to be accepted but just `SomethingElse` to be rejected, then there is no type in the type system that acts that way.  The way [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) work is that you can assign a value of type `AliveCat | SomethingElse` to `Possibly<AliveCat>` then you can also assign a value of type `SomethingElse` to `Possibly<AliveCat>`.  So, on the face of it, `Possibly<V>` is not a type.

---

It seems more like you want `Possibly<V>` to act as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on a candidate type `T`. That is, instead of `T extends Possibly<V>`, you want `T extends Possibly<V, T>`.  It sounds like you're asking for `T extends Possibly<V, T>` to be true when reading a value of type `T` might give you a value of type `V`.  If so, you're just saying that the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `T` and `V` should not be [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  You can express that like this:

```
type Possibly<V, T> = (V & T) extends never ? V : unknown
```

But unfortunately this will only prevent calls of `feed(someCat)` if `typeof someCat` absolutely is known to the compiler as definitely not being an `AliveCat`.  And even with the following  completely unrelated versions of `AliveCat` and `DeadCat`:

```
declare class AliveCat { food: number; }
declare class DeadCat { dead: true; }
```

the compiler sees that an `AliveCat & DeadCat` may indeed exist:

```
const zombieCat: AliveCat & DeadCat = { dead: true, food: -10 };
feed(zombieCat); // okay
```

and so `tom` is also accepted:

```
feed(tom); // no error
```

If you can change `AliveCat` and `DeadCat` to form distinct members of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) then things start working:

```
declare class AliveCat { food: number; alive: true }
declare class DeadCat { dead: true; alive: false }
// alive property discriminates

feed(tom); // error as desired
```

But I will assume you can't do that.

---

Backing up, you're looking for the compiler to accept the same types that are accepted when you do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  To a rough approximation, you can write `x as T` if `(typeof x) extends T` or if `T extends (typeof x)`. If that's what you want, then really we're saying `T extends Possibly<V, T>` if and only if `T extends V` or `V extends T`.  That could be expressed as:

```
type Possibly<V, T> = [V] extends [T] ? unknown : V;
```

And then even with your non-discriminated `DeadCat` and `AliveCat`, things start working:

```
function feed<T extends Possibly<AliveCat, T>>(cat: T): asserts cat is T & AliveCat {
    if (cat instanceof AliveCat) {
        cat.food++;
    } else {
        throw new Error(" :( ");
    }
}
```

Let's make sure

```
schrodingersCat as AliveCat; // okay
feed<AliveCat | DeadCat>(schrodingersCat); // okay
schrodingersCat.food++; // AliveCat

tom as AliveCat; // error    
feed(tom); // error

const zombieCat: AliveCat & DeadCat = { dead: true, food: -10 }; 
zombieCat as AliveCat; // okay
feed(zombieCat); // okay
```

Looks good!

---

Note that you wanted `feed()` to be an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that returns `cat is AliveCat`. But since `typeof cat` might already be narrower than `AliveCat`, this is not allowed.  Instead we can just write `cat is typeof cat & AliveCat` or rather `cat is T & AliveCat`, so that whatever type `cat` starts off as, `T & AliveCat` is a subtype of it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-8rsa0PhW5VcooAF4YfRxdpN-2KM5Jmn7dw8ZxaHx+dYyrwAWgAjAAGMz26Gwg4LgzLkXdpBoH4gUZsFjO0CQWAIZB0CwXBWmIMgKBoOgGAAJnVDVymyOxV2xJRjy0XQDGMDs-QgfdfH8eC+AqaxRH6TxmQ8PdvHwkwQBwrRlDotVHQyIjsiqKIYjiBIOhwkpCOCIQOKHQpyKGMo2KE2ckFTRoMy9IlkO6RMxJwNINTGCYkDRKA5gWFZcR2fYjgZElEVue49WeN4PktJBvj+QFgWjcFwKhGNYXhczkUsnS9MxPiFEM-EuWJUkOwpfAqS5WlGARM543VTV2U5GkeRwPkBSFQKcFFDVNSlY963yp0VTVMVNS1HUDUeA0jRNc1LWtW0b0CFizGnWT009NoaU7HKXzCMMIyjQIPLjHLejI4oFBTcs5J6rMXzzAsiyGksIDLN1KwUnAazlBUcyUhRpyHCLjrUo7e0nfs7yHEcewnKcvx-cBoDgRBUB0CZ8BQHR9DgiTBNCJDEvcNDtD0Qx8BMdqENsckHFUpRdy8A8CKBrIpIiaJ8FieJEgGgSsZnPICmmwY1OJ4iOK6nbepwXjmxpFSZqpjTximGZdIxAzNiMpAAG1lgAXW8lEhY2MX3gc-4gTs5Z1LG1zIVvOEEWuCzUW5-zFnjYKCUUkkyUi6K0rihkwZKjgUsN7lZ0yiBBQuvLKs4Qra2KzVTDK5AKsq7UGhq-VDSexqrRtO1rY6trOvm7qq0Ufrmcuxt1pGqBbomlOps3HA5u2+SGYemT80LLhixGraKyL1x9rrQ7G3jU722TtcX2ul5OCzwcMBLzvpxyCIHyXbEmbXBk872FHPDww8VFrLRzyvUwbxHp8k-EAajrfD8e-X7ES93z82HMIA)

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate that you described the various intermediate solutions with their requirements and shortcomings, and I learned some things along the way. Like, when I was trying to invent this constraint myself and had to check "is M a member of union U" I couldn't get that to work (In `type CouldBe<M, U> = U extends M ? 1 : 0; type CHIbH = CouldBe<"henk", "henk" | "ingrid">;`, `CHIbH` resolves to `0 | 1`, not `1`). Hadn't thought of checking the intersection though.

Comment: (continued) Same with `asserts cat is AliveCat`, which I thought should work out of the box, but that was just me not being used to thinking with intersection types yet. It makes sense now that the keyword is `is`, not `asserts cat extends AliveCat`. Although I suppose I'm still not quite getting why `zombieCat` is too narrow for an `AliveCat`... but I'll try again in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

In response to your new information, I interpret your question to be that you need to either

- only accept a type which extends `AliveCat`, or
- discriminate an `unknown` type at runtime before acting on the discriminated type. I'll show examples of both.

Given these types/values for both examples:

```ts
type Cat<IsAlive extends boolean = boolean> = {
  isAlive: IsAlive;
};

type AliveCat = Cat<true> & { food: number };
type DeadCat = Cat<false>;

declare const garfield: AliveCat;
declare const tom: DeadCat;
declare const schrodingersCat: unknown;
```

#### Using a generic to only accept a type that extends `AliveCat`

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsAPASQM4EEA2BLAbtCAD2AgDsATVKAIwHtbMI5SoBeG+x5gPjagG8AUFCjYMOfAC4oaLHggBuQQF8lg0JChz88YH12JgAJwCuEXgDIBUAGb1y00iYC21CEair14aABEm5Lr6CIg2cJio5mrkEADGmHBG0LG0pKh6AOaJNtgQmA5aEhC6SjHxicmp6VDAtM7S-nCBCKVxCUlQKWl6qLEAFka05NikGe6outImpADWpLQA7qRqNtOxwNipthAQ5FCIACpQRCQUVNrFCNwAFLEI0gcAlALCnQgAdHZDANTfSsqCQQ2Hbka5ZIw5PLkR4KKAAejhUFoMyBIOu-DEF2kxjMABpbPZpABWfEnIxwAAKgzA0gA5LhwmZacoYfDEcjScQyJRCvJdIDgbtrrVnKy4QAqV4iKAAPTlgnQRgyLjIeloNhqPigtMazWAtNEVHmejgqFQ2AypDg1EYNVoUDAiTgzggJA86s1mlpF10tPerwOWp1AV9hqgxqgpvNlutttqnugtIMOPMfqlUEDkCoHrA1PcoG1mKKBoqolIKWcjo2Nog-ul0szibCEQgBrE4doJrNFqtNbtCe1Kb91wATABmAAsROe4rhArRvQGQxGYyMEwQYsl9dlct3e-3CqVKtIao1GkT0zmi1IbaNncj3ZjffjjvJLrdSLPQZ9CDTIkb2qXvMSy3h2XbRr2cb2ue2rJqYqbvKOk7TlAs6CEAA)

```ts
function feed <T extends AliveCat>(cat: T) {
  cat.food++;
}

feed(garfield); // ok
feed({isAlive: true, food: 5, extraProp: 'value'}); // ok, extends AliveCat

feed(tom); /*
     ^^^
Argument of type 'DeadCat' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AliveCat'.
  Type 'DeadCat' is not assignable to type 'Cat<true>'.
    Types of property 'isAlive' are incompatible.
      Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'.(2345) */

feed(schrodingersCat); /*
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AliveCat'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Cat<true>'.(2345) */
```

#### Discriminate an `unknown` type at runtime (using a [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates))

Here, runtime validation of the unknown value is performed to ensure that its shape/properties align with the type that is asserted. Doing this gives confidence that the value can be safely acted on according to the type you think it will be in the code block:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsAPASQM4EEA2BLAbtCAD2AgDsATVKAIwHtbMI5SoBeG+x5gPjagG8AUFCjYMOfAC4oaLHggBuQQF8lg0JChz88YH12JgAJwCuEXgDIBUAGb1y00iYC21CEair14aABEm5Lr6CIg2cJio5mrkEADGmHBG0LG0pKh6AOaJNtgQmA5aEhC6SjHxicmp6VDAtM7S-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)

```ts
function isType <T = never>(value: unknown, typeValidator: (value: unknown) => boolean): value is T {
  return typeValidator(value);
}

function feed (something: unknown) {
  const isAliveCat = isType<AliveCat>(something, u => (
    typeof u === 'object'
    && (u as any).isAlive === true
    && typeof (u as any).food === 'number'
  ));

  if (isAliveCat) {
    something; // AliveCat
    something.food++; // ok
  }
  else {
    something; // unknown
  }
}

feed(garfield); // ok, gets fed
feed(tom); // ok, might get fed if is an AliveCat (but won't because it isn't)
feed(schrodingersCat); // ok, might get fed if is an AliveCat
```

---

### Original answer

I think you are looking for a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsAPASQM4EEA2BLAbtCAD2AgDsATVKAIwHtbMI5SoBeG+x5gPjagG8AUFCjYMOfAC4oaLHggBuQQF8lg0JChz88YH12JgAJwCuEXgDIBwqADN65aaRMBbahCNLVg9eGgARJnJdfQREWzhMVHMlDWgATQhgABVaACEIQJIjF2xSCGCEPm0IEIAfKEC4QuA1cggAY0w4I2gG2lJUPQBzFttsCExHLQlShCV6ppa2jq6oYFoXaSqaicbm1qh2zr1UBoALI1pyPO6PVF1pRJT0zKSPXPzVn1sTUgbgbA67CAKACgaCCuSVSGSyDzyBV0AEprCJsLYoACEAA6MQlWFCEQiQHAFH2Y4AakJShEyigg2icOxuPxDmJCigAHoAFQ2bHYgB63M57KgAAUjpAjKAoAByAnkMVQci0CBUUi0PREMR6b5xcUrXRilF-ABMAGYDQBOWEspk+DnAQ60ADuUHy9oAokYjkY-gAiKCSP5QD3Q0lQZQqF6-ch-PY2k6kM5GC4IAPMplQWgAa0EtjDEYOR2jsfjejgVBKMMZTOTaYzWcjudO5xCRcqQVLSZT6ar-wWLigjZLCbLbI5UB5I9HPMEMA6+DjXxYtERGrFWoQ0oW8z84r7wGlLjgIBo0DgUFyXTgqeg7kBJip+Ww1o8680qBMtn6DQGpGAmH3tGnzTAVC2ne+zzPs0BKmBRgojIC77GIUC2o2eQkJ+s6RAANFsU4eHo94UoQYCtKgqCzvMtDim8qaKrapDSv0cZ4jYyQbkuzYrqICpKlhLhgC0cDUIwZGPtAYoGMYZjcDqfLMZAVDzlAhG0MKopiuiozStMojvIsvGfAJEAonyIgySJERRBA0rwYqejtDxfH6UJi7iRZuqGgArHqZoWkAA)

```ts
type Cat<IsAlive extends boolean = boolean> = {
  isAlive: IsAlive;
};

type AliveCat = Cat<true> & {
  food: number;
};

type DeadCat = Cat<false>;
type YetToBeDeterminedCat = AliveCat | DeadCat;

declare const garfield: AliveCat;
declare const tom: DeadCat;
declare const schrodingersCat: YetToBeDeterminedCat;

function feed(cat: YetToBeDeterminedCat) {
  if (cat.isAlive) {
    cat.food++;
  } else {
    cat.food++; /*
        ^^^^
    Property 'food' does not exist on type 'DeadCat'.(2339) */

    throw new Error(" :( ");
  }
}

feed(schrodingersCat); // ok
feed(schrodingersCat as AliveCat); // ok
feed(schrodingersCat as DeadCat); // ok

feed(tom as AliveCat); /*
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Conversion of type 'DeadCat' to type 'AliveCat' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'DeadCat' is not comparable to type 'Cat<true>'.
    Types of property 'isAlive' are incompatible.
      Type 'false' is not comparable to type 'true'.(2352) */
```

Comment: Thanks, but that requires the caller to cast to AliveCat to get the error, which wasn't my goal... but it does give me inspiration for a possible workaround. Also I suppose I should have specified that the Cat types here are out of my control and can't be changed, like the isArray example. Nice improvement of `declare const` btw.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence in trying to come up with a solution :) Unfortunately, neither of the new ones match the requirements of accepting Garfield and Schrödinger's Cat (and only them), _at compile time_, as the first one rejects Schrödinger's and the second one accepts Tom.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom That's true: I'm just trying to offer something that will actually compile. The current requirements are incompatible with TypeScript. 

Comment: While I appreciate the effort to provide "something that compiles", if requirements simply cannot be met, "no" is also a valid answer :)
In any case, jcalz proved that it is in fact possible!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to just use a cast (or assertion, in good Typescriptian) where this already works. Unfortunately this extra bit of safety comes at a price, because the intent of the code becomes much less clear.

```
/**
 * @param cat may also be something else, it's checked at runtime
 */
declare function feed(cat: AliveCat);
feed(garfield);
feed(tom as AliveCat); // cast error

// cast allowed, though now it looks as if the programmer already
// knew it's alive
feed(schrodingersCat as AliveCat);
```

This may be mitigated a bit with a helper function:

```
/**
 * Cast v to O for the type system, keeping in mind that the runtime type
 * of v may not actually be O!
 *
 * TODO needs shorter name. assume?
 */
function tentativeCast<I, O extends I>(v: I): O {
    return v as O
}

feed(tentativeCast(schrodingersCat)); // inferred
```

It's a little bit dangerous though, because the result of `tentativeCast` still does have a technically illegal type, which may accidentally end up in some local variable anyway. Fortunately, it can be made safer with some more runtime overhead:

```
class Uncertain<T> {
  readonly #value: T;
  constructor(value: T) { this.#value = value; }
  get value() { return this.#value; }
}

type Possibly<T> = T | Uncertain<T>;

declare function feed(cat: Possibly<AliveCat>): void;

/**
 * Cast v to O for the type system, keeping in mind that the runtime type
 * of v may not actually be O!
 *
 * TODO needs shorter name. assume?
 */
function tentativeCast<I, O extends I>(v: I): Uncertain<O> {
    return new Uncertain(v as O);
}

feed(tentativeCast(garfield)); // allowed
feed(tentativeCast(tom)); // not allowed
const certainlyAlive: AliveCat = tentativeCast(schrodingersCat); // not allowed, Uncertain<AliveCat> is not AliveCat
feed(tentativeCast(schrodingersCat)); // allowed, Uncertain<AliveCat> extends Possibly<AliveCat>
```

Comment: "_cat may also be something else, it's checked at runtime_" This is not correct. Any argument provided for a parameter must be assignable to its type: otherwise a compiler error will occur. Looking at this code in the playground demonstrates this: https://tsplay.dev/wOJlyW

Comment: Obviously, that's why the casts are needed. ;) "may also be something else" applies _at runtime_", i.e. that you're allowed to pass something that you wrangled into the correct type even if you're not sure it actually is of that type.

Comment: @jsejcksn As for the code you linked, there are 2 errors which are both only related to `tentativeCast`, which is an optional function for documentation purposes only. The first error is caused by me simply forgetting to pass 2 type parameters. I've removed that version. For the second error, this is because you extracted the tentativeCast to a const whose type you did not declare, so it inferred `unknown`. While `unknown` should be accepted as input to tentativeCast, it won't work if it's its return type. See https://tsplay.dev/w16nON for a fixed example.

Comment: Using an [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) directly is no different than abstracting it to a function which uses generic inference. `4 as AliveCat` is the same as `tentativeCast<number, AliveCat>(4)`: they just produce different error messages (2352 and 2344, respectively)

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, to the compiler it is (almost) the same. The purpose of this function is to try to inform some poor guy reading this code in a year about what's going on.